# Can't Load Codeigniter Custom Library

Tags: codeigniter

Library

```
class getLang {
   public function getText($en, $ar) {
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $lang = $CI->session->userdata('language');
      if ($lang == 'en') {
         $string = $en;
      } else if ($lang == 'ar') {
         if (!empty($ar)) {
            $string = $ar;   
         } else if (empty ($ar)) {
            $string = $en;
         }
      }
      return $string;
   }
}
```

Controller

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {
   public function test() {
      $this->load->library('getLang');
      return $this->getLang->getText('text', '');
   }
}
```

When I run home/test I get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Home::$getLang

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 6
```

I already loaded the custom library in config/autoload.
Looks like the library isn't loaded, I also tried loading it in the controller, still doens't work!
How can I solve this?

Comment: in which folder your library located? full path please.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan The full path is application/libraries/getLang.php

Answer (score 9):

CodeIgniter's documentation clearly states that class name and file name must be capitalize.  From [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html):

> 1. File names must be capitalized. For example:  Myclass.php
> 2. Class declarations must be capitalized. For example:  class Myclass
> 3. Class names and file names must match.

That's probably why it isn't correctly loaded.

On a side note, a class named `getLang` sounds wrong.  It sounds like a method.  I would suggest a name such as `Language`, `Translator`, ...

Edit: The documentation also asks to access your library by using the lower case version of the name. Example: `$this->getlang->getText(...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I actually decided to include my function in another library that is loaded and works fine.