# Codeigniter Custom Library loading error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My custom Library not loading through auto loading or through manual code. I checked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779231/cant-load-codeigniter-custom-library) and [Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

#### library/Faq.php

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Faq {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->model('Faq_model');
    }
    public function recentFaqs(){
        return $this->Faq_model->getFaqs();
    }
}
```

> Loaded the library $this->load->library('faq');
>
> Called its function $this->faq->recentFaqs();

I got the following error
A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Faq::$faq
>
> Filename: controllers/Faq.php
>
> Line Number: 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably because your constructor is trying to load a model using `$this`. But `$this` needs to be a reference to CodeIgniter. So, you need to obtain a CodeIgniter reference before loading the model.

```
class Faq {
  public $CI;

  public function __construct(){
   $this->CI = & get_instance();
   $this->CI->load->model('Faq_model');
  }

  public function recentFaqs(){
    return $this->Faq_model->getFaqs();
  }
}
```

The reference to CI `$this->CI` should be used in any function of this class that will call codeigniter classes. By saving it as a property of your class it becomes easy to reuse.